# Difference between the default access specifier and protected access specifier in java

Tags: java, access-specifier

I was trying to learn java and when I went through access specifiers I had a doubt. What is the difference between the default one if none is specified and the protected access specifier in java?

Comment: The difference is clearly visualized in [this table](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33627846/276052).

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The `protected` specifier allows access by all subclasses of the class in question, whatever package they reside in, as well as to other code in the same package. The default specifier allows access by other code in the same package, but not by code that is in subclasses residing in different packages. See [Java Language Specification Section 6.6](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.6).

EDIT: Per request of Michael Schmeißer (so others don't have to read through the comments or follow a link to find this): all members of interfaces are implicitly public. It is, in fact, a compile-time error to specify any access specifier for an interface member other than `public` (although no access specifier at all defaults to public access). Here's the full set of rules from the JLS for class members (see the above link for the rules for packages, top-level classes and interfaces, and arrays):

> A member (class, interface, field, or method) of a reference (class, interface, or array) type or a constructor of a class type is accessible only if the type is accessible and the member or constructor is declared to permit access:
>
> - If the member or constructor is declared public, then access is permitted.
> - All members of interfaces are implicitly public.
> - Otherwise, if the member or constructor is declared protected, then access is permitted only when one of the following is true:
>
> > - Access to the member or constructor occurs from within the package containing the class in which the protected member or constructor is declared.
> > - Access is correct as described in [§6.6.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.6.2). (This clause refers to the rules that allow derived classes to access protected members of superclasses; §6.6.2 starts: *"A protected member or constructor of an object may be accessed from outside the package in which it is declared only by code that is responsible for the implementation of that object."* It then elaborates on that.)
>
> - Otherwise, if the member or constructor is declared private, then access is permitted if and only if it occurs within the body of the top level class ([§7.6](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.6)) that encloses the declaration of the member or constructor.
> - Otherwise, we say there is default access, which is permitted only when the access occurs from within the package in which the type is declared.

Comment: One clarification: The default access specifier allows access for all subclasses no matter what package they are in.The default modifier widens access to all classes in the same package compared to the protected access modifier.

Comment: @david.dionis - That is not correct. A field, method, or other member with default access is not accessible from a subclass declared in a different package.

Comment: Wow that is true. I just tried it and learned something new. Thank you and +1!

Comment: @Ted Hopp Your answer is correct so I up-voted it, however, I would ask you to add the fact that the default visibility is actually public within interfaces. (Also mentioned within the JLS section: "All members of interfaces are implicitly public.")

Answer (score 55):

This Java [tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) may be of some use to you.

```
Modifier    | Class | Package | Subclass | World

public      |  Y    |    Y    |    Y     |   Y

protected   |  Y    |    Y    |    Y     |   N

no modifier |  Y    |    Y    |    N     |   N

private     |  Y    |    N    |    N     |   N
```

Answer (score 6):

Long story short:

`default` member is available in *all the other classes of the same package*;

`protected` member is available in *all the other classes of the same package* **and** *in any other class of any other package as long as that class extends the class containing your protected member.*

Answer (score 4):

### Protected Access specifier - there are two ways to access protected data

1. The protected data members,protected methods of a class will be visible to the other Classes if they resides in **same package**
2. Using **Inheritance**

   means we can use the protected data of that class by Inheriting that class.

### Default access specifier- Only one way to access default data

Default restricts the access only to package level , even after extending the class having default data members ,we won't be able to access.

#### Example

**To check it for default remove protected keyword for int x in ProvideProtected  , a compile time error will be generated.**

```
        1. SuperClass

        package nee.superclass;

        public class ProvideProtected {
            protected int x=800;

        }

        2.Subclass


        package nee.subclass;

        import nee.superclass.*;

        public class AccessProtected extends ProvideProtected 

        {   
        public void accessProtected()
            {
                System.out.println(x);
            }

            public static void main(String[] args) {
                AccessProtected obj=new AccessProtected();
                obj.accessProtected();

            }

        }
```

Answer (score 4):

Protected Access Modifier :- Anything marked as protected is visible within the same package and also visible in the subclass .

Default access :- Default is not a keyword . It applies when no access modifier is specified . It is basically a package level modifier. Anything which is having such an access is visible in the same package .

Now the difference can be explained better with the help of an example

**package p1**

```
public class A
{

protected void fn()
{

}

}
```

**package p1**

```
public class B
{

A a1 = new A();

a1.fn();// fn() is visible inside the same package

}

}
```

Now we come to a subclass in different package

**package p2**

```
public class D extends A

{

void test()

{

A a1 = new new A();

    //a1.fn() -->  would give compilation error
fn();

super.fn();

}

}
```

`fn(), super.fn()` will not give an error.

So, the difference is in the subclass the method can't be called via reference of super class. Either  You can call it directly or use super.

Note that `super.fn()` must be a part of non-static method.

Answer (score 2):

- protected - same package+other package which extends this class.
- default - same package only.

Example:

```
package p1;
protected class Parent{
}

import p1.*;
class Child extends Parent{}
```